# windows subsystem for linux bash not working

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to switch to subsystem for linux on my windows device, but when I type the bash command it gives me this error, why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LouFW.png)

```bash
Processing fstab with mount -a failed.

<3>WSL (29) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:347: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (29) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:351: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (29) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:524: execvpe /bin/bash failed 2
<3>WSL (29) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:533: Create process not expected to return
```

Comment: 1) Please use text (vs. screenshots).  2) Typing "bash" from a DOS prompt is *NOT* how you invoke WSL.  SUGGESTION: Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/get-started-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: Thank you for adding the text - it helped.  The central problem is the initial "fstab with mount -a failed" error.  This might help: https://superuser.com/a/1691425/47938.  The solution there was `wsl -s Debian`.  I would still encourage you to look at the Microsoft link I cited, to verify you didn't inadvertently "miss a step".

Comment: @paulsm4 While I don't recommend `bash.exe` for starting WSL, for now it's still a valid ([although deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands)) command for doing so.  And apologies - I mistakenly tagged you in my response to the OP in that "off-topic" comment earlier.

Comment: @Berkant Keep in mind that Stack Overflow questions should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems"* (i.e. *"unique to software development"*). Non-programming WSL issues or questions are usually better suited for one of the sister sites here such  as [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), or (if the question is Ubuntu-specific) [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). In this case, I'd recommend deleting your question here and reposting it on Super User. Thanks!

Comment: FIXED: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423048/i-am-getting-error-on-windows-subsystem